# Setting up Android Bootstrap in IntelliJ

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, android-bootstrap

I found this open source project: [Android Boostrap](http://www.androidbootstrap.com/). However, I am having some troubles with getting it run in IntelliJ. I have followed their own instructions, but still I am running into some problems. Note that I just started using IntelliJ. I cannot even describe the errors I am getting very precisely, since I am not sure about what exactly is causing them. Here is the screenshot of what I have:

[image]

Navigating to the problem:

[image]

How do you suggest me to solve it?

Another snapshot regarding unsupported import:
[image]

Comment: have you tried removing those libraries it says are not used, by clicking the "-" button?

Comment: Nope, that does not help... another thing: `import static android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;` is not supported, that means it cannot import this library. I added the snapshpot in the question, see EDIT

Comment: @adavis, I found out that my project was not building due to another error (missing library), and this did not cause any problem.

Comment: Ok good, glad you got it working